# CheckBox not working properly in new Android Material Library, not able to see actual checkmarks

Tags: android, android-checkbox

I have done 2 things:

1. Migrate to Android X
2. Migrate App to AppCompat

After doing these 2, checkboxes are not working properly inside Listview. Here is my code:

build.gradle:

```
dependencies {

    implementation files('libs/httpmime-4.3.jar')
    implementation files('libs/httpcore-4.3.jar')
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.0.0-rc01'
    implementation 'androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v4:1.0.0-rc01'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.0.0-rc01'
}
```

CheckBox row:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/facets"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/ten_dip"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:orientation="horizontal"  
    android:weightSum="1.0" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="0px"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="0.97"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/title_tv"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="0.25"
            />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/title_tv_number"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="0.75"
             />
    </LinearLayout>

    <CheckBox
        android:id="@+id/facets_img_checkbox"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        />

</LinearLayout>
```

ListView Layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:weightSum="1">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight=".1"
        android:paddingTop="10dp"
        android:paddingBottom="10dp"
        android:background="@color/white"
        android:elevation="2dp"
       >

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/back_button_filter"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:paddingLeft="10dp"
        android:paddingRight="10dp">

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:id="@+id/back_button"
                app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_caret_back"
                android:padding="5dp"
                />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:paddingLeft="10dp"
                android:text="Filters"
                android:gravity="center_vertical"
                android:textSize="18sp"
                android:textColor="@color/black_555555"
                android:fontFamily="sans-serif"/>
        </LinearLayout>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/reset_button"
        android:paddingLeft="10dp"
        android:paddingRight="10dp"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:text="RESET"
        android:textColor="@color/linkcolor"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:fontFamily="sans-serif"
        android:textSize="18sp" />
</RelativeLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:background="@color/click_menu"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/five_dip"
    android:paddingBottom="5dp"
    android:paddingLeft="10dp"
    android:paddingRight="10dp"
    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
    android:layout_weight=".1"
    android:weightSum="1">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:text="Sort by"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:textColor="@color/black_555555"
        android:fontFamily="sans-serif"
        android:textSize="14sp"
        android:layout_weight=".25"/>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight=".75"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:weightSum="2"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        android:gravity="center_vertical">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/relevence_facets"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@drawable/blue_rectangle_button"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:paddingTop="8dp"
            android:paddingBottom="8dp"
            android:textSize="14sp"
            android:text="Relevance"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            android:fontFamily="sans-serif"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dp"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/freshness_facets"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:paddingTop="8dp"
            android:paddingBottom="8dp"
            android:textSize="14sp"
            android:text="Freshness"
            android:fontFamily="sans-serif"
            android:textColor="@color/black_555555" />
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>



    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/facets_item"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_weight=".73"
        android:weightSum="1">

        <ScrollView
            android:id="@+id/search_facets"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight=".35"
            android:fillViewport="true"
            android:background="@color/click_menu"
            >


            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:weightSum="7">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/location_tv"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="0dp"
                    android:text="Location"
                    android:gravity="center|left"
                    android:paddingLeft="10dp"
                    android:textColor="@color/black_555555"
                    android:textSize="@dimen/fourteen_sp"
                    android:textStyle="bold"
                    android:background="@color/white"
                    android:layout_weight=".75"/>
                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/experience_tv"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="0dp"
                    android:gravity="center|left"
                    android:paddingLeft="10dp"
                    android:text="@string/experience"
                    android:textColor="@color/black_555555"
                    android:textSize="@dimen/fourteen_sp"
                    android:layout_weight=".75"/>

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/salary_tv"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="0dp"
                    android:gravity="center|left"
                    android:paddingLeft="10dp"
                    android:text="@string/salary"
                    android:textColor="@color/black_555555"
                    android:textSize="@dimen/fourteen_sp"
                    android:layout_weight=".75"/>

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/industry_tv"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="0dp"
                    android:gravity="center|left"
                    android:paddingLeft="10dp"
                    android:text="Industry"
                    android:textColor="@color/black_555555"
                    android:textSize="@dimen/fourteen_sp"
                    android:layout_weight=".75"/>

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/fun_area_tv"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="0dp"
                    android:gravity="center|left"
                    android:paddingLeft="10dp"
                    android:text="Department"
                    android:textColor="@color/black_555555"
                    android:textSize="@dimen/fourteen_sp"
                    android:layout_weight=".75"/>
                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/job_type_tv"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="0dp"
                    android:gravity="center|left"
                    android:paddingLeft="10dp"
                    android:text="Job type"
                    android:textColor="@color/black_555555"
                    android:textSize="@dimen/fourteen_sp"
                    android:layout_weight=".75"/>
                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/top_companies_tv"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="0dp"
                    android:gravity="center|left"
                    android:paddingLeft="10dp"
                    android:text="Companies"
                    android:textColor="@color/black_555555"
                    android:textSize="@dimen/fourteen_sp"
                    android:layout_weight=".75"/>

            </LinearLayout>
        </ScrollView>

            <ListView
                android:id="@+id/list_view"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_weight=".65"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:background="@color/white"
                android:divider="#e7e7e7"
                android:dividerHeight="1dp"
                android:horizontalSpacing="@dimen/ten_dip"
                android:verticalSpacing="@dimen/ten_dip">
            </ListView>
        </LinearLayout>


        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/refine_text1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight=".07"
            android:background="@drawable/button_yellow"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom"
            android:text="Apply filters"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:textColor="#fff"
            android:textSize="@dimen/sixteen_sp" />
</LinearLayout>
```

ScreenShots: 
[image: This is what it looks like when it is not clicked]

[image: when selected]

[image: When one is deselcted]

I am not able to see actual checkmarks and on clicking one checkbox, it changes state of all the other in the list.

Comment: Might be the problem of white background below the checkbox..change background color of activity and check

Comment: No, it is not working.

Comment: Got it working. It is some sort of google library compatibility issue with below oreo versions. Just Add checkbox.jumpDrawablesToCurrentState() to get it working

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*(Posted answer on behalf of the question author).*

I got it working.

It is some sort of Google library compatibility issue with below Oreo versions. Just add `checkbox.jumpDrawablesToCurrentState()` to get it work.